# Expanding content within UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm building a cell-based game that essentially works like dominoes: you start with one tile in the center, then connect additional tiles to it that can branch out in all directions. I have my game table all set up and working great... now I just need to make it scroll to accommodate the expanding content.

So, this doesn't seem to fit easily into a `UIScrollView`'s built-in behavior. For one thing, cells expand in all directions – potentially going into the negative coordinate space of the `UIScrollView`. As far as I can tell, `UIScrollView` does not allow an actual `CGRect` with size AND origin to be defined for the scrolling content area. It appears you can only define a width and height for the content area that extends from point (0,0). Is this true, or am I missing something?

Assuming my understanding of the content area limitations are correct, how would one ideally handle this problem? My go-to idea would be to shift all subviews into positive coordinate space as the game board expands, then update the ScrollView's `contentOffset` property to counter the shift and make the transition invisible. I just want to make sure I'm not reinventing an inferior wheel before I start developing this.

Thanks in advance for any and all ideas!

Answer (score 1):

I believe your idea is the good one, every time a tile is added, you may need to adjust your content view in order to be able to center on the tile that just was added.
Hence if this is "backward" (-x or -y) and your on top of your view (or nearly), you'll have to extend your contentView (surely the same way you do for +x, +y) and thus, adjust every of your tiles with the translation you did to your contentView's down-right corner.

Answer (score 0):

Following up... yep, that did it. I set up the display so that it redraws the grid of cells from the upper-left corner. Whenever a new row or column of cells is added to the top or the left, the UIScrollView's `contentOffset` shifts by the newly added pixels to hide the change in content position.